# Can't navigate a JTable by the arrow keys after using setRowSelectionInterval(int, int)

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtable, selection

I'm extending JTable and I have a populateData() method that I'm using to load data into the table model. In this method I'm using:

```
setRowSelectionInterval(tableRow, tableRow);
```

And it is working as I want it to, which is to highlight the first row. But there is one problem: I cannot move the selection to the next row by the down arrow key. I have to click on any row (even the one that is highlighted) with the mouse to be able to navigate by the arrow keys.

```
void populateData(Collection<Book> b) {
   myModel.populateData(b);
   if (myModel.getRowCount() > 0) {
      setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
   }
}
```

Note: I'm enabling only row selections. Column and cell selections are disabled.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess focus in not on the table so it doesn't react to key presses. You may need to add:

```
table.requestFocusInWindow();
```

If this doesn't work the instead of setRowSelectionInterval(...) try using:

```
table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
```

Comment: Yeah, I also think it's a focus problem, and I tried before to request the focus but it didn't work. The changeSelection also didn't work, it just highlighted the row (the same as setRowSelectionInterval). Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Mota, Focus can only be requested on a component that is displayed on a visible GUI. You question doesn't state when your code is being executed. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem is you need more help.

Comment: Now it's working with requestFocusInWindow. Before I was requesting the focus from the table itself, and that didn't work, now it works when I request the focus from the frame. Thank you so much.